# YouTube API "Queries per day" exceed in about 3 hours

Tags: c#, youtube, youtube-api, asp.net-core-webapi, youtube-data-api

I created a program that uploads videos to YouTube using the YouTube Data API.

My program's flow is:

1. Login google account in google page using the URL
   `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?access_type=offline&prompt=consent&include_granted_scopes=true&client_id={YouTubeAppId}&redirect_uri={RedirectURL}&response_type=code&scope={Uri.EscapeDataString(https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile)}`
2. Exchange code to access token: `POST` `https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token`
3. Get user's channel's IDs: `GET` `https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet,statistics&mine=true&access_token={AccessToken}`.
   Then I select the video and split it to 1Mb chunks.
4. Get upload URL: `POST` `https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/videos?uploadType=resumable&part=snippet,status,contentDetails&access_token={token}` with model
5. Send chunks of video using URL from `Location` header in previous step.

Also I've got 10min timer which refreshes access token.

```
foreach (SocialLogin item in logins.Where(x => (x.UpdatedOn.AddSeconds(x.ExpirationSeconds) - DateTime.Now).TotalSeconds < 600))
        {
            SocialLogin youModel = await _youtubeService.RefreshTokenAsync(item);
            youModel.UpdatedOn = DateTimeOffset.Now;
            youModel.ExpirationSeconds = 3600;
            await _loginRepository.UpdateAsync(youModel);
        }
```

This function gets all YouTube logins from the database and refreshes tokens for those logins that expire less than 10 minutes using `POST` on the URL `https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token`.
I uploaded couple of 15mb videos and it works well, but after it Queries per day quota counted about 2500 queries. I added breakpoints for all methods which make API calls and counted them all. There was about 50 requests at all. After couple of hours I sent another 2 30mb videos and this quota had about 8000 queries. How is this quota calculated? And what does it calculate?
Now it's 0 but yesterday it was 8120.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you'll have to acknowledge that the YouTube Data API does not account the amount of megabytes of video content the you're uploading via its [`Videos.insert`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert) endpoint.

Then you'll have to acknowledge that the API is not accounting for the number of endpoint calls.

Given that each endpoint has [attached a quota cost](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost), the YouTube Data API is *accounting for the sum of units of quota cost* of all endpoint calls you make on a particular day.

For example, having a daily quota allocation of 10000 units, since the cost of one video upload is 1600 units, you're allowed to upload at most 6 videos, irrespective of their actual size (if not considering the cost of other API calls that you made).

Comment: I missed this page. Now I think it's clear. Maybe later I have to fill out a form and send a YouTube team to expand this limit...